# Greeting words in emails

Tags: grammar, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['Thanks and Regards,' or 'Thanks and regards,'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40625/thanks-and-regards-or-thanks-and-regards)

In emails, there are greeting words such as *Best regards* and *Best wishes*. Should we capitalize the second word, so that they become *Best Regards* and *Best Wishes*?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you can use both in informal letters. However, when writing official/formal letter/e-mail, do not capitalize your second word.

Answer (score 0):

These are sentences (or sentence fragments) and not titles, so write them like "Best regards" not "Best Regards". It's also more readable this way and also follows how you would use other valedictions such as "Yours sincerely" in more formal letters.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically speaking "Best regards" is correct, however I would argue common usage for writing "Best Regards" as well.