# Is it acceptable to write "Best Regards" with a capital "R" and not followed by a comma?

Tags: expressions, business-language, letter-writing, valediction, style-manuals

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> ['Thanks and Regards,' or 'Thanks and regards,'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40625/thanks-and-regards-or-thanks-and-regards)
> [Should you use a comma/period after "Thanks"/"Regards" in email signatures?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2329/should-you-use-a-comma-period-after-thanks-regards-in-email-signatures)

In my company, we use "Best Regards" with a capital "R", not followed by a comma - is that acceptable?

I have searched the Internet, but I did not find any "official" style guide that clearly condemns or endorses the use of capitalization in the valedictory phrase. The vast majority of examples in the guides I found only use a capital letter at the beginning (e.g. "Yours faithfully"), but that is not something I can base a change of corporate policy on.

The second part of my question is about the comma. The sites I found have a slight tendency to use a comma, but I did not find any conclusive information on that either.

Our communication with customers and prospects has the following style:

> Dear Mr John Doe
>
> [Text]
>
> Best Regards
>
> Signature

As you can see, we use capitalization liberally and punctuation very sparingly.
Please provide some proof for your opinion if you take the time to respond to my question.